# Disable Nintendo 3DS Scroll Function while Firing Keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, scroll

I've been trying to build a moveable div in a webpage that runs in the web browser of the Nintendo 3DS game system.  Basically, when I use the + Control Pad (which corresponds with the keycodes of a regular keyboard's arrow keys), the div slides around the page.  Unfortunately, since my page size is required to be too large to fit directly into the 3DS viewport, the browser automatically scrolls over faster than my div can move into view.  I've came up with various techniques employing `overflow: hidden;`, `position: fixed;` and

```
    $(document).keydown(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //call my function to move the div around
    });
```

The 3DS browser doesn't actually use a conventional "scrollbar", though; it just scrolls anyway.  And it's `position: fixed;` support is pretty bad.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to stop the page from scrolling but allow the div to move around (and scroll over a bit to show more of the page when the div hits the edge of the viewport)?

This is my first post on stackOverflow.  Thanks for any ideas!!!

**EDIT:** You can see the code here: [Cloud9 IDE link](https://c9.io/epicaleb/demo-project) and in action here: [DEMO link](https://c9.io/epicaleb/demo-project/workspace/html/index.html)

Comment: Can you please make a codepen with a more complete code please? It will help us better understand and see if you have any validations errors, weird css, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have this problem with all mobile devices.
The best way to deal with position fixed on mobile devices for me is to completely remove scroll capability from the page and emulate it with JavaScript, then to change position on the new scroll event.
But also, you can make an unmovable page and scroll only parts you need to, so your element will not move at all.

```
html,body {
    overflow: hidden
}

#divID {
    overflow: auto; // if you want just vertical scroll overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Would you please see my links? Thanks!  Also, I want the page to scroll a bit to show more of the page when my div hits the edge of the viewport.